# Android Volley sending some times the request

Tags: java, android, request, spinner, android-volley

Good afternoon to all, i´m having troubles using Volley library. I´m doing the following:

First, in the fragment i select a name from a spinner and immediately it has to appear information in a table layout. So i´m basically doing this:

```
public void FunctionName(String url, final Map<String,String> json){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest post = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JsonAll = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
               for (int i = 0; i < JsonAll.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Object = JsonAll.getJSONObject(i);
                    TableRow row= new TableRow(getActivity());
                    string = Object.getString("string");
//here i create the textview that will be add in the table row 
//and row in table layout already initialized in the OnCreateView().
                    TextView textcodigo1 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    textcodigo1.setText(string );
                    row.addView(textcodigo1);
                    tableAgenda.addView(row);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("otro error:",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = json;

            return map;
        }
    };


    queue.add(post);
    //AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(post);


}
```

I call this function in here:

```
Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int i;
                Set set = copy.entrySet();
                Iterator iter = set.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                    for (i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++) {
                        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals(entry.getValue().toString())) {
                            key = entry.getKey().toString();
                            params.put("codi", key);

                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "prueba:" + entry.getKey().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
                FunctionName(URL, params);
//here is where i´m calling my function 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

For some reason i receiving as answer, for example:
123
456
123
456

I only need:
123
456 but it repeats twice.
I was debugging and when the Function Name finishes it goes to `StringRequest.class` -> `ExecutorDelivery.class` -> `Handler.java` -> `Looper.java` 
and then goes again to the function and executes it.
Please help i don't understand why is this happening, i have already tried :

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0,
  DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

But nothing works. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: i think the problem is that your spinner called the onitemselectedlistener twice. could you also paste your activity/fragment wherein you implement the spinner.

Comment: hi, the Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener is in the:      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)